# Navigation Drawer list elements not working

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

on navigation drawer i want two function: import and export my database. Sounds simple but at the momment it is not working. The navigation drawer list with import element and export element is not clickable why is so?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        // nav drawer title
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

        // used to store app title
        private CharSequence mTitle;

        // slide menu items
        private String[] navMenuTitles;
//      private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
        private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            tap_on_plus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageNewNote);
            Contact_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
            Set_Referash_Data();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("some error", "" + e);
        }

        // tikras folderis "/Android/data/com.strategeens"
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/BackupFolder");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            if (direct.mkdir()) {
                // directory is created;
            }
        }


        /////////////naujibundle///////////

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
 //       navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], 1/*navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)*/));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], 1/*navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)*/));       

        // Recycle the typed array
//        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); 
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    public class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        importDB();
                        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1"  +  position);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2"  +  position);
                        exportDB();
                        break;
                    }
                  // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                  mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                  setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
/////////////////////visas kitas sudas///////////pabaiga

    // importing database
    private void importDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.strategeens.drugnotes"
                        + "//databases//" + "drugsManager";
                String backupDBPath = "/BackupFolder/drugsManager";
                File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Set_Referash_Data();
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    }

    // exporting database
    private void exportDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.strategeens.drugnotes"
                        + "//databases//" + "drugsManager";
                String backupDBPath = "/BackupFolder/drugsManager";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
//        default:
//            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent add_user = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddUpdateDrug.class);
            add_user.putExtra("called", "add");
            add_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(add_user);
            finish();

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my **activity_main.xml** file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>   

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNewNote"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tap_on_a_plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/newNote" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageNewNote"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:text="Export" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Import" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ListView that is your Drawer has Views listed after it in the layout, causing those Views to be z-ordered above the Drawer and to interfere with click events. Move the ListView in your layout so that it is listed after the RelativeLayout. Also, if you're not going to use the `frame_container` FrameLayout, you can remove it.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNewNote"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tap_on_a_plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/newNote" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageNewNote"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:text="Export" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Import" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>   

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, i thought that problem is with xml file, but could tell me more how to properly edit xml?

Comment: Thanks, now I realized in Android XML, any elements placed at the top of the XML file, is rendered / layered in the app from the bottom. As the XML is parsed from top to bottom, elements are rendered from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

your method should be like this :

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // selectItem(position);
            switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        importDB();
                        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1"  +  position);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2"  +  position);
                        exportDB();
                        break;
                    }
                  // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                  mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                  setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: list elements is still not clickable :(